# SAT inequality problem

Tags: inequality

I've been studying from Collegeboard SAT practice tests, and I've stumbled with a inequality problem, which I can't seem to understand even with SAT answer explanation.I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help me.

$$ y ≤ 3x+1 $$
$$x-y > 1 $$
Which of the following ordered pairs (x, y)  satisfies
the system of inequalities above?
$$A) (−2, −1) $$
$$B) (−1, 3 )$$ 
$$C) (1, 5 )$$ 
$$D) (2,-1)$$

*edit*

This is the answer explanation they give me:

Choice D is correct. Any point (x, y) that is a solution to the given system of inequalities must
satisfy both inequalities in the system. Since the second inequality in the system can be
rewritten as $$y < x − 1$$, the system is equivalent to the following system.

$$ y ≤ 3x+1 $$
$$x-y > 1 $$

Since $$3x + 1 > x − 1$$ for $$x > −1 $$and$$ 3x + 1 ≤ x − 1$$ for$$ x ≤ −1$$, it follows that $$y < x − 1$$ for $$x > −1$$ and $$y
≤ 3x + 1$$ for$$ x ≤ −1$$. Of the given choices, only (2, −1) satisfies these conditions because $$ −1 < 2 − 1 = 1. $$

Comment: What is it that you don’t understand? Plug each possible answer in and see which, if any, works.

Comment: Yes, fixed it. I want to find the analytical way of solving it.

Comment: @Retweetfire What do you mean by that?

Comment: In this kind of problem there really is no "analytical" solution. You could draw a picture of each line, show the side of the line that satisfies each inequality, and plot the points to see where they lie, but just testing each pair is the best solution. There are now two  answers that do  that. I think the explanation you were given is terrible. It's correct, but a foolish amount of work for this problem, particularly if you encounter it on a timed exam!

Comment: The only way to see if the any of the given ordered pairs satisfy the given inequalities, is by testing them.

Comment: @mrnovice I believe he was asking for a method of solving which derived some more simple inequalities and then testing which of the options fits (however I do agree, your answer is clearly the quickest way).

Answer (score 2):

$$y \leq 3x+1$$

$$y < x-1$$

$\implies y \leq \min(3x+1,x-1)$.

Consider when does $3x+1=x-1$? Solving for it gives us $x=-1$.

Hence when $x<-1$, $\min(3x+1,x-1)=3x+1$

When $x \geq -1$, $\min(3x+1,x-1)=x-1$.

Hence if $x <-1$, $$y \leq 3x+1 \tag{1}$$

and if $x \geq 1$, $$y<x-1 \tag{2}$$.

For $A$, $x=-2$, check rule $1$, $3x+1=-5 < y = -1$, hence rule it out.

For $B$, $x=-1$, check rule $2$, $x-1=-2 < y=3$, hence rule it out.

For $C$, $x=1$, check rule $2$, $x-1=0 < y=5$, hence rule it out.

In case the question is wrong, let's check $D$.

$x=2$, check rule $2$, $x-1=1 > -1=y$, hence $D$ is a valid point.

Remark: During SAT, sometimes they just want to see you being able to substitute values and verify rather than solving the problem. Use mrnovice answer during SAT.

Answer (score 1):

$-2--1=-1\not> 1$ so reject $(A)$

$-1-3=-4\not>1$ so reject $(B)$

$1-5=-4 \not> 1$ so reject $(C)$

Therefore the answer is $(D)$

You could also create a new inequality by writing $$3x+1\geq y$$

$$x-1 > y$$

$$\implies 4x>2y\implies 2x>y$$

Using this inequality, it is quite easy to eliminate all options except $(D)$

Comment: OP asked for analytical way.

Answer (score 1):

$$y\leq3x+1$$ $$x-y>1\implies y<x-1$$
You can solve this graphically

[image]

The region which solves these inequalities is the region below the two lines. By plotting the 4 points, you'll see option D is the only one which lies in the region.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to plot the graph of the two equations to get the region which satisfies this condition.
Graph: [The graph for this condition](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?source=wordcloud&i=plot+x-y%3E1+and+y%3C%3D3x%2B1)

Although. I don't see why you should not simply plug the values? It's easy enough